# Android: enableReaderMode - ReaderCallback not invoked

Tags: android, kotlin, nfc

I've a problem with the NFC reader mode in android. I can enable the reader mode, but the `onTagDiscovered` callback is never invoked. The phone recognizes the tag, it vibrates shortly.

Here my code:

```
try {

    val nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);

    if (nfcAdapter == null) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No NFC module :-(", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } else if (!nfcAdapter.isEnabled) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "NFC not enabled :-(", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } else {
        val options = Bundle()
        options.putInt(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_READER_PRESENCE_CHECK_DELAY, 5000)

        nfcAdapter.enableReaderMode(
            this,
            NfcAdapter.ReaderCallback() {
                fun onTagDiscovered(tag: Tag) {
                    Log.println(Log.DEBUG, null, "Discovered!");
                }
            },
            NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_NFC_A or NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_NFC_B or NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_SKIP_NDEF_CHECK,
            options
        );

        Log.println(Log.DEBUG, null, "Reader Mode");

    }
} catch (e: Exception) {
    Log.println(Log.ERROR, null, e.toString());
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated**

The problem is with scope of the callback

I've not tried to invoke the callback it in this manner I normally implement it in the Activity scope, I don't know if that is causing a problem also

This has been tested now and defining the Callback method as part of the call to `nfcAdapter.enableReaderMode` does not work, the Interface should be implemented in the `Activity` scope

e.g.

```
class MainActivity : NfcAdapter.ReaderCallback, AppCompatActivity() {
  override fun onTagDiscovered(tag: Tag) {
                    Log.println(Log.DEBUG, null, "Discovered!");
                }
```

then

```
nfcAdapter.enableReaderMode(
            this,
            this,
            NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_NFC_A or 
            NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_NFC_B or 
            NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_SKIP_NDEF_CHECK,
            options
        );
```

Comment: `or` _is_ bitwise OR in kotlin. A logical OR would be `||`.

Comment: Seems I've read the docs for the wrong type, you are right on an `Int` it is bitwise, so it might be the scope then.

Comment: Updated and tested now and it was the second issue with the Callback scope.

Comment: Thank you! callback scope solved the problem. 